# SQL code to get a certain activity a rank of 1?

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, dense-rank

```
select whse,
    user_id,
    shift,
    tran_nbr,
    to_char(sched_start_date, 'HH24:MI:SS') as STRTUP,
    to_char(sched_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as DATE1,
    act_name,
    dept_code,
    num
from (
    select whse,
        user_id,
        shift,
        tran_nbr,
        sched_start_date,
        to_char(sched_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
        actl_time,
        act_name,
        dept_Code,
        dense_RANK() over (
            partition by to_char(sched_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
            user_id order by user_id,
                sched_start_date asc
            ) num
    from my_hdr
    ) X
where to_char(sched_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS') between '02/09/2017 04:00:00' and '02/09/2017 10:00:00'
    and actl_time > '0'
    and ACT_NAME = 'JFSTRTUP'
order by whse,
    user_id,
    to_char(sched_start_date, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

I am trying to return whenever `JFSTRTUP` is found to give it the rank (num) of '1'. Right now I get some `JFSTRTUP` where `num <> 1`

SQL Output:

```
WHSE USER_ID Shift  TRAN NBR    STRTUP      DATE1       ACT_NAME    DEPT_CODE  NUM
008   AMANY   1B    900197641   05:28:00    02/09/2017  JFSTRTUP    ORDERFILL   1
008   BTORR   1C    900197629   05:58:00    02/09/2017  JFSTRTUP    ORDERFILL   3
008   CROM    1B    900197644   05:29:00    02/09/2017  JFSTRTUP    ORDERFILL   1
```

I would like to have that second row return a 1 instead of 3.

Comment: `to_char(sched_start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS') between '02/09/2017 04:00:00' and '02/09/2017 10:00:00'` will not work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before your ORDER BY clause, after the filter for JFSTRTUP:

```
AND num = 1
```

Note: You don't need to use user_id in the dense_rank order by clause - you are partitioning by user_id, so the rank will never take user_id into account. There is never a reason to use a value in both the partition by and order by clause of window functions.